# Extending UserCreationForm: password not saved

Tags: python, django

I've successfully created and extended the `UserCreationForm` to get `email`, `first_name` & `last_name`. It works fine in inserting all values. But I think the `password` field is not being saved. I'm using the built-in `auth` object to authenticate the user to login to my site. When the use register in the site and tries to login the `password` doesn't matches and the user cannot login. When I change the `password` from `admin`, I can login successfully. So, can anyone help me?
This is how I've extended `UserCreationForm`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.TextInput()
    last_name = forms.TextInput()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

[image: How I change my password usgin admin?]
  Now, I click `the form` link and I change the password.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you change the password from the admin? You put the password directly into the field input? Or is it the password reset procedure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The problem

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
                 ^
                 |___ super of UserCreationForm is ModelForm!
```

Your code is calling super of `UserCreationForm` and not the super of your own form `RegistrationForm`. (The super of `UserCreationForm` being `ModelForm` has no idea how to handle user registration like password saving)

**The result is that `user.set_password()` wasn't being called anywhere**

However, I'd say no need to call `user.set_password` again since your `super` already does.

`UserCreationForm.save()` is defined as follows:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

[Source code on github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L99)

### Solution

You should have something like this

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    # Call save of the super of your own class,
    # which is UserCreationForm.save() which calls user.set_password()
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False) 

    # Add the things your super doesn't do for you
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

Comment: thanks! but can you explain me why password was saved using `email` field only but not while I used other fields with my previous code.

Comment: I highly doubt it has anything to do with "email only" or not, since your password was blank in the DB, it's clear the problem is user._set_password wasn't being called anywhere (manually or through super). Maybe you forgot you added `user.set_password()`  when you tried the `email` only version :P